# how to cast string to generic type

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, casting

I've class name which is in string format,I need to execute dynamically function and cast result into dynamically

```
    Type type = Type.GetType(method.NameSpace + "." + method.ClassName, false);
    //

      Type calledType = Type.GetType(namespaceName + "." + className + "," + assemblyName);
             //this function return object type of class type which is I've created from string className      
var result=  calledType.InvokeMember(
                                methodName,
                                BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static,
                                null,
                                null,
                                obj);
```

OR AlTERNAtely

```
public T CAST<T>(Object o){
//some mechanism
}

CAST<type >(result);
```

gives type or namespace name expected ..
How do I Cast dynamically generated class type to generic type

Now I need to cast var result to a Type type (dynamic class). How?

Comment: *Why* do you need to make that cast? Please give us the bigger picture.

Comment: And what is the string you wish to cast? The type of result is `object`, not `string`.

Comment: Well I've execute method dynamically from the new added assembly in system. So All methods list and required information saved into database and from database field i need to execute and get result from that function like as we do hard coded in code file, I ve tried to do var result=  (type)calledType.InvokeMember(
                            methodName,
                            BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static,
                            null,
                            null,
                            obj);
but this gives error how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is `Convert.ChangeType`. Below is a samples for invoking `MyMethod` with `string[]` parameters.

```
public static string MyMethod(string s, int i, DateTime d)
{
    return s + " " + i + " " + d.ToString();
}

public T Execute<T>()
{
    //They are all strings in object array
    object[] myparams = new object[] {"test","3","04/03/2012" };

    Type[] types = this.GetType()
                       .GetMethod("MyMethod")
                       .GetParameters()
                       .Select(p=>p.ParameterType)
                       .ToArray();

    object result = 
        this.GetType().InvokeMember(
        "MyMethod",
        BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static,
        null,
        this,
        myparams.Select((s,i)=>Convert.ChangeType(s,types[i])).ToArray()
        );

    return (T)result;
}
```

Comment: in your case mymethod return a string and parameter type is also string ,int etc but  what if mymethod return list of object and parameters are also object type  i need to cast parameter and return type also and dynamically ....so what i want is to cast var result to type from earlier created from string class name.. isnt that possible?

Comment: `i need to cast parameter and return type` This is also what I do in the answer. `MyMethod`s parameters are *int*,*string* & *datetime* , `myparams` on the other hand, is string array

Comment: In your case params are in string array  but in my case there is a lot object and list object coming as params and i need to filter them and pass it as params any clue? I want like                 public T CAST<T>(Object o){
//some mechanism
}Filter and out the reuired param

CAST<type >(result);